# Apache 2.4.4 - rotatelogs error - parameter is incorrect

Tags: apache

I have searched all day for an answer to this.  I issue this directive in httpd.conf:

CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs logs/access_log.%Y-%m-%d 86400" common

This worked in 2.2.  common is defined earlier in the file.

I keep getting this error when trying to start the service:

AH00104: unable to start piped log program 'bin/rotatelogs logs/access_log.%Y-%m-%d 86400': The parameter is incorrect.

Any help will be most appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Ok, so I'm on Windows Server 2008.  I had to add .exe to rotatelogs.  Could have sworn I tried that before but I guess not.  All set.

Comment: Thanks to let us know. I was stuck in same problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows OS path to rotatelogs have to contains .exe file extension to not produce error "could not open reliable pipe to" in error log. 
Example : CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/access 15M" common

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue with rotatelogs running on Windows Server.
You should pay attention to the slash that is used in the SRVROOT variable within httpd.conf. It should be like this:

```
Define SRVROOT "C:/apache24"
```

and not like I did:

<strike>Define SRVROOT "C:\apache24"</strike>

If the path is like the last one, server will start, but will not write any logs.